# css float "squeeze" elements when page width is small

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to float two elements next to each other in the same container without the right-most element getting squeezed down below when the window size is reduced? Instead, I would like the right element to be covered by the window.

here's the css:

```
#logo {
margin-left: 400px;
float:left; 
}

#loginbox {
margin-top: 15px;
float:left;
height: 70px;
width: 375px; 
}
```

and the html

```
<div class="header">
        <div id='logo'>
            <img id='logo-img' src='graphics/banner2.png' alt='Logo' height=200px width=700x />
        </div>
        <div id='loginbox' class='login'>
            <form id='login' >
                <span style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">Login</span>
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="text" id='login-email' value='email' />
                <input type='text' id='login-password' value='password' />
                <input type='submit' value='login'/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br style='clear:both' />
    </div><!-- end header -->
```

thanks!!

Comment: I think what you want to do is set the widths to % instead of px... that way it should scale.

Comment: which two elements are we talking about? the two login boxes or the login div and the logo?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set a hard width for the header and for the cells:

http://jsfiddle.net/ByWM2/

```
<div class="header">
        <div id='logo'>
            <img id='logo-img' src='graphics/banner2.png' alt='Logo' />
        </div>
        <div id='loginbox' class='login'>
            <form id='login' >
                <span style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">Login</span>
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="text" id='login-email' value='email' />
                <input type='text' id='login-password' value='password' />
                <input type='submit' value='login'/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end header -->​

.header { width:700px; overflow:hidden; }

#logo {
background:lime;
min-width:300px;
float:left; 
}

#loginbox {
background:cyan;
float:left;
height: 70px;
min-width: 400pxpx; 
}​
```

Comment: thank you so much!! this solved the problem. I needed to set a fixed width for header.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `min-width` for `#loginbox`:

```
#loginbox {
  margin-top: 15px;
  float:left;
  height: 70px;
  min-width: 200px; /* set this to the max width you'd like it to squeeze to */
  width: 375px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put an enclosing `<div></div>` of `height: 70px` or whatever the largest of the two floats is, and then set it to have a `min-width: 200px;` or, again, whatever width you want the minimum to be.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

soln 1:
Set width or min-width on the container (header) equal to or greater than the widths of the 2 divs *if* those 2 are both of known width. You don't have a width on #logo, but I would normally presume a logo has a reliable (i.e. constant) width.

```
 #header{width: 900px; /*or whatever*/}
```

soln 2:
use css3 properties (requires IE9+ or one of the *cool* browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table):

```
 #header{display:table}
 #logo, #loginbox{display:table-cell}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a few ways to solve this problem, here's one:

Assuming the left column's width is known, you can set the right column to position absolute and set its margin left to the width of the left column's width so it will position properly. you also have to set the position of the parent div to relative in order for this to work. here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JKXrV/1/